# Internal server error in dot net mvc: unable to resolve service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework, service

I am trying to use MVC with a controller a view a model and the database.
But I premise I do not know how to use entity framework in my case to connect the model and the database. So I get this runtime error:
"**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'WebCoreFly.Models.FlightsList**' while attempting to activate 'WebCoreFly.Controllers.HomeController"

My code consists in:
the controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private FlightsList l;

        public HomeController(FlightsList theList)
        { l = theList; }

        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(l.Flights);
        }
    }
```

the Model Code for Flights:

```
public partial class Flights
    {
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long Id_Destination { get; set; }
        public string Id_Source { get; set; }
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime Time { get; set; }
        public string Id_Plane { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeOfArrival { get; set; }
    }
```

and the model for FlightsList:

```
public class FlightsList
    {
        private FlyDBContext context;

        public FlightsList(FlyDBContext ctx)
        {
            context = ctx;
        }

        public IQueryable<Flights> Flights => context.Flights;
    }
```

finally I have defined my dbcontext:

```
public class FlyDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public FlyDBContext(DbContextOptions<FlyDBContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<WebCoreFly.Models.Passengers> Passengers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCoreFly.Models.Bookings> Bookings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<WebCoreFly.Models.Flights> Flights { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my startup code, I configure services to accept my dbcontext with a link to **Existing SQL Database** called Fly:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddDbContext<FlyDBContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=Fly;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False"));
        }
```

And this is the Configure method of startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

My question is: who is responsible to pass to my controller the flights list? and since the flightlist is tied to the dbcontext, is the problem somehow related to the fact I did not use entityframework? (For semplicity Idid not post the code for my view, but I can do it if necessary)

Comment: You could create your own controller factory to do this, but I've not worked with entity framework so I'll wait to see what others suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is coming because of the dependency Injection. Here How the application would know that **Flights List** object requires in Home Controller. To fix this you have to configure it in StartUp.Cs class Configure Service method.

```
 services.AddSingelton<FlightsList>();
```

There are various ways to configure it like **Transient**, **AddScoped** etc.

It is better if you use repository pattern here. Register here the Interface. like following.

```
 services.AddSingelton<IRepository, FlightsList>();
```

In controller side.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IRepository l;

    public HomeController(IRepository theList)
    { l = theList; }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(l.Flights);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hi, thanks that fixed the error but i get another error now:
InvalidOperationException: Cannot consume scoped service 'WebCoreFly.Models.FlyDBContext' from singleton 'WebCoreFly.Models.FlightsList'.

Comment: I hope someone is going to help me with this further error. I have copied the approach in Pro Asp Net Core 2 book. But I did not use entity framework for the migration because I have already a database.

Comment: In the book after the migration it is like magically working. But I do not understand how the application knows to pass  dbcontext from my database to the FlightList constructor.

Comment: Well,if you look closely to the ConfigureService method on the second line . you already registered **FlyDbContext**                                   
 ` services.AddDbContext<FlyDBContext>(option=> "db location")`